# How to create a List of Lists based on certain value in a List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
p = [
     [84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 111, 102, 32], 
     [9, 9, 73, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 98, 101, 97, 117, 116, 105, 102, 117, 108, 108, 121, 46], 
     [78, 101, 101, 100, 32, 116, 111, 32, 102, 105, 103, 117, 114, 101, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101, 46], 
     [105, 116, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 108, 111, 118, 105, 110, 103, 32, 105, 116, 46, 46, 46], 
     [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 46, 46, 46, 33, 33, 33]
    ]
```

I want to create a list of lists of each value to the value 32. And if there is not the value 32 in the list just put everything in a new list.
I want the result to be like this.

```
 p = [
      [[84, 104, 105, 115, 32], [105, 115, 32], [97, 32], [116, 101, 115, 116, 32], [111, 102, 32]], 
      [[9, 9, 73, 116, 32], [105, 115, 32], [98, 101, 97, 117, 116, 105, 102, 117, 108, 108, 121, 46]], 
      [[78, 101, 101, 100, 32], [116, 111, 32], [102, 105, 103, 117, 114, 101, 32], [108, 105, 110, 101, 46]], 
      [[105, 116, 32], [97, 110, 100, 32], [108, 111, 118, 105, 110, 103, 32], [105, 116, 46, 46, 46]], 
      [[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 46, 46, 46, 33, 33, 33]]
    ]
```

Is it possible to make it like that? if so, could you please give me a solution?

Thanks all.

Comment: "do my homework for me"

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please attempt your own code before coming onto this website, then put up the attempt and the issue, and we can help

Comment: FWIW, `b' '.join(map(bytes, p))` returns `b'This is a test of  \t\tIt is beautifully. Need to figure line. it and loving it... 1234567890...!!!'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VALUE = 32

p = [
     [84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 111, 102, 32], 
     [9, 9, 73, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 98, 101, 97, 117, 116, 105, 102, 117, 108, 108, 121, 46], 
     [78, 101, 101, 100, 32, 116, 111, 32, 102, 105, 103, 117, 114, 101, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101, 46], 
     [105, 116, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 108, 111, 118, 105, 110, 103, 32, 105, 116, 46, 46, 46], 
     [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 46, 46, 46, 33, 33, 33]
    ]

result = []
for pi in p:
    sublists = []
    start = 0
    try:
        while start < len(pi):
            idx = pi.index(VALUE, start)
            sublists.append(pi[start:idx + 1])
            start = idx + 1
    except ValueError:
        if start < len(pi):
            sublists.append(pi[start:])
    result.append(sublists)

print(result)
>>> [[[84, 104, 105, 115, 32], [105, 115, 32], [97, 32], [116, 101, 115, 116, 32], [111, 102, 32]], [[9, 9, 73, 116, 32], [105, 115, 32], [98, 101, 97, 117, 116, 105, 102, 117, 108, 108, 121, 46]], [[78, 101, 101, 100, 32], [116, 111, 32], [102, 105, 103, 117, 114, 101, 32], [108, 105, 110, 101, 46]], [[105, 116, 32], [97, 110, 100, 32], [108, 111, 118, 105, 110, 103, 32], [105, 116, 46, 46, 46]], [[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 46, 46, 46, 33, 33, 33]]]
```

Comment: It's a beautiful solution. I totally forgot about list append a list. Kept wondering how to create other lists automatically blocked my mind. Thank you so much.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this approach is O(n^2) while only O(n) is required.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I don't think that's the case. I've made a change to avoid some list copies that should make it clearer. Each `index` operation starts where the previous one finished, so in total they traverse each sublist once.

Comment: @jdehesa `list.index` is O(n) so that alone means you are repeatedly iterating over the sublists.

Comment: @JaredGoguen `list.index` is O(n) because _at worst_ it has to go through the whole list, but the time it actually takes is proportional to the distance from the starting search position to the actual element (or the end). Here each `index` operation only goes through a segment of the list, and no two operations go over the same segment, so it's not just O(n), it's also Ω(n) (like any other algorithm for this problem).

Comment: @jdehesa That's a valid point. Unrelated, your code still uses `while pi` but you are no longer mutating `pi` in place.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like explicit is the best approach here.

```
def split_on_value(iterable, value):
    result = []
    current = []
    for item in iterable:
        current.append(item)
        if item == value:
            result.append(current)
            current = []

    if current:
        result.append(current)

    return result

print [split_on_value(sub, 32) for sub in p]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using itertools:

```
from itertools import chain

p = list(chain.from_iterable(p))

places = [i+1 for i, a in enumerate(p) if a == 32]

places.insert(0, 0)
places.append(len(p))

new_data = [p[places[i]:places[i+1]] for i in range(len(places)-1)]
```

Output:

```
[[84, 104, 105, 115, 32], [105, 115, 32], [97, 32], [116, 101, 115, 116, 32], [111, 102, 32], [9, 9, 73, 116, 32], [105, 115, 32], [98, 101, 97, 117, 116, 105, 102, 117, 108, 108, 121, 46, 78, 101, 101, 100, 32], [116, 111, 32], [102, 105, 103, 117, 114, 101, 32], [108, 105, 110, 101, 46, 105, 116, 32], [97, 110, 100, 32], [108, 111, 118, 105, 110, 103, 32], [105, 116, 46, 46, 46, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 46, 46, 46, 33, 33, 33]]
```